# Проблема с кодировкой кириллицы в intellijeIdea

Tags: java, windows, кодировка, intellij-idea, junit

Столкнулся с проблемой в отображении кириллицы при использовании аннотации в @DisplayName в junit.
Проблема наблюдается только на ОС windows(мак и линуксе отображает как нужно), проблема появилась после обновления на 18  java(прошу не предлагать использовать другую версию).
При выводе вместо корректного описанию получаем артефакты

[image: скрин с ошибкой]

При смене настроек с utf8 на 1251 летит остальная кодировка по проекту, но ошибка уходит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробовал все решения из данной ветки https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231291/intellij-idea-incorrect-encoding-in-console-output. Ничего не помогло, как и все остальные варианты предлагаемые на просторах сети.

Answer (score 0):

В похожем топике читала, что помогает апгрейд IDEA до последней версии. Возможно, вам тоже поможет

Comment: К сожалению версия уже стоит последняя

Answer (score 0):

Возникла такая же проблема, открыла файлы, которые скачала с гугл-диска.
Изначально установлена кодировка UTF-8.
Сменила её на windows-1251.
Появилось окно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбрала Convert.

Потом опять сменила кодировку с windows-1251 на UTF-8, в появившемся окне выбрала Convert.

Результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Решил похожую проблему сменой поставщика JDK.
В File -> Project Structure -> Project -> SDK сменил Oracle Open JDK 20.0.1 на Amazon Correto 17.0.7